# IE6 with fixed <ul> does not work

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-6

I have a `<ul>` which has `{position:fixed;z-index:10;}` css properties.
Inside it there are `<li>`-s that have `{display:block;margin-top:15px;}` 
css properties. It contains `<p>` with some text and li has a background 
image with say 50px width and height.

This `<ul>` is in body tag where thet is a rest of site:

```
<body>
<ul id="myProblematicUl"></ul>
<div id="restOfTheSite"></div>
</body
```

It works fine for all the browsers I have tested (about 7-8 browsers). It does not work only for IE6. The problem is that it pushes down the restOfTheSite to the bottom of the last li, instead of being next to each other.

What can be the problem. I can no way fix this.

Comment: How vital is IE6 support really?  It's an old browser with tiny market share that's only going to shrink further over time.  If it works in IE7+ and the other major browsers then I'd just call it job done.

Comment: Does your body tag have `position: relative;`?

Comment: How are you positioning `#myProblematicUl` and `#restOfTheSite` next to each other? If you're floating them, applying `display: inline` to the floated elements seems to solve any float problems in IE6.

Comment: @GordonM, unfortunately IE6 is still used by a lot, I have to factor in IE6 because for one of my websites, 14.23% of all IE visit use IE 6, thats around 14,000 individual visits a month.

Comment: @wanovak no body does not have, but the li of ul-s have

Answer (score 1):

position:fixed doesnt work in IE6 if i recall. you have to use position:absolute and some other IE6 hack